# Join two tables according to column value specified in parent table

Tags: mysql

My master table is "ordered_product" table.

I want to join another table according to the value resides in "product_id_type" column inside it.

If my "product_type_id" = 1 , I want to join "allopathy_medicine" table . If it is 2 I want to join with "ayurveda_medicine" table.

If the "product_type_id" in "ordered_product"  table is 1 , means I can only allow to get product name from "allopathy_medicine" table.

The primary objective is to  show the product names in a page. [image]

```
SELECT ordered_product.*,
    CASE
WHEN product_type_id = 1 THEN allopathy_medicine.name AS allopathyName
WHEN product_type_id = 2 THEN ayurvada - medicine.name AS ayurvedaName
ELSE allopathy_medicine.name
END
FROM ordered_product
INNER JOIN allopathy_medicine ON allopathy_medicine.id = ordered_product.product_id
INNER JOIN ayurvada - medicine ON ayurvada_medicine.id = ordered_product.product_id
```

The above code is my code , but its not working , it shows syntax error in php my admin. Am lookin forward for answers.

Thank you
shinoy

update : I found this code is working from answers , does anyone know how to shrink the code:

```
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    al.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN allopathy_medicine al ON al.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 1 AND op.order_no = orderNo //passed externaly
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `ayurvada-medicine` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 2 AND op.order_no = orderNo
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `veterinary_medicine` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 3 AND op.order_no = orderNo
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `fitness` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 4 AND op.order_no = orderNo
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `cosmetic` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 5 AND op.order_no = orderNo
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `sugical_products` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 6 AND op.order_no = orderNo
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `laboratory_products` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 7 AND op.order_no = orderNo
UNION ALL
SELECT
    op.order_no,
    op.product_type_id,
    op.qty,
    op.amount,
    ay.name,
    pt.name AS pdttype
FROM ordered_product op
JOIN `animal_food` ay ON ay.id = op.product_id
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = op.product_type_id
WHERE op.product_type_id = 8 AND op.order_no = orderNo
```

Comment: Be aware the including mathematical operators within table/column identifiers is a cataclysmically bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be any more straightforward than this.

```
SELECT
    op.product_id,
    op.product_type_id,
    IFNULL(al.name, ay.name) AS name
FROM ordered_product op
LEFT JOIN allopathy_medicine al ON al.id = op.product_id AND product_type_id = 1
LEFT JOIN ayurveda_medicine ay ON ay.id = op.product_id AND product_type_id = 2
```

Comment: I have 8 product_type_id   to check , so code will be larger , any shorter method?

Comment: 8 product_type_id , meaning you have 8 tables (including `allopathy_medicine` and `ayurveda_medicine`) ? I doubt it can get any shorter. I mean, it is already shorter than doing the `UNION`...

Comment: Okay ,you updated the answer . okay. But the previous code is working fine .New code not working.

Answer (score 0):

One product type can be or type 1 or type 2 so you inner join fails ever

If the row don't match always you should use  left join

```
SELECT ordered_product.*,
    CASE
WHEN product_type_id = 1 THEN allopathy_medicine.name 
WHEN product_type_id = 2 THENm2.name 
ELSE allopathy_medicine.name
END  medicine_name
FROM ordered_product
LEFT  JOIN allopathy_medicine ON allopathy_medicine.id = ordered_product.product_id
LEFT  JOIN `ayurvada - medicine` m2 ON m2.id = ordered_product.product_id
```

and you should not use tablename with minus sign .. you should use underscore ..but if your shce contain this char you should wrap the table name with backtics

and you can assign different column name alias inside case when condition but only one common column name alias after end

Comment: Its not working in my mysql . shows syntax error

Comment: answer  updated  removed  different column name alias inside case when because not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `product_id` in the main table be unique, and only occurs in at most one of the other two tables, you should be able to just do a series of joins here:

```sql
SELECT op.*, COALESCE(alm.name, aym.name) AS medicine_name,
       CASE WHEN aym.id IS NULL THEN 'allopathy' ELSE 'ayurvada' END AS medicine_type
FROM ordered_product op
LEFT JOIN allopathy_medicine alm ON alm.id = op.product_id
LEFT JOIN `ayurvada-medicine` aym ON aym.id = op.product_id;
```

Comment: In my case product_id  is not unique , same id  resides inside allopathy_medicine  and also ayurveda_medicine . The above code is working . But my product_id is not unique any other way?

Comment: Well if an product `id` matches to _both_ medicine tables, what do you want to display?

Comment: Thats why I added product_type_id  in the ordered_product table. With the help of that I can differenctiate , isnt' it?  or In your way  , I'm willing to implement unique constraint  in "id" field of  allopathy_medicine tabel and ayurveda_medicine table how can I implement ?

Comment: Your comments and code are contradicting each other.  Edit your question and add sample data, then show us the output you want.

Comment: Okay , thanks for your support and I will update the question soon.